# How to make image change color while mouse is moving over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First off, sorry for the weird title, I don't really know a better way of describing it.

Basically I want the image to change color while the mouse is moving (hovering) over it, but for it to stop when the mouse is still,

**While the mouse is stationary, color doesn't change,**

**While the mouse is moving, color changes.**

I know there is the hover attribute in CSS, but it only has 2 states, when the mouse is hovering over it, and when it is not, what i'm looking for is something a bit trickier.

Hopefully that explains it :/

Comment: You are looking for `onmousemove` event !

Comment: Please take a look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/uf8pcgpr/) and let me know if that's what you want !

Comment: That seems a bit heavy-handed for hovering over text when :hover exists in CSS.

Comment: Please provide your code in its current state so we can see the transition you're trying to apply to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS animations, using Javascript to toggle a class when the mouse moves over the image, or stops doing so.

The image will need to be wrapped within another tag, if it isn't already, and then a pseudo-element will need to be added to that tag, positioned to sit directly on top of the image, with an initial `opacity` of `0`. We ensure the image is visible behind the pseudo-element by setting the [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) property of the latter. When the mouse first moves over the image it is, optionally, converted to grayscale and the `background-color` of the pseudo-element begins animating. When the mouse stops moving, the timeout in the JavaScript adds a class to the parent element which sets the [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) property of the pseudo-element to `paused` and, when the mouse is moved again, this class is removed.

You can refine & tweak everything in this (e.g., removing the image's `filter`, adding/removing `keyframes`, chaning the `mix-blend-mode`, adjusting the `animation-duration`) just by editing the CSS, no need to touch the JavaScript.

```js
var figure=document.querySelector("figure"),
    img=figure.querySelector("img"),
    timer;
img.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    figure.classList.remove("paused");
    setTimeout(function(){
        figure.classList.add("paused");
    },300);
},0);
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
figure{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    transition:-webkit-filter .25s linear 99999s,filter .25s linear 99999s;
}
img:hover{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(1);
    filter:grayscale(1);
    transition-delay:0s;
}
figure::after{
    animation:colours 5s linear infinite;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    left:0;
    mix-blend-mode:overlay;
    opacity:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    transition:opacity .25s linear 99999s;
}
figure:hover::after{
    opacity:.75;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
figure.paused::after{
    animation-play-state:paused;
}
@keyframes colours{
    0%{background:#f00;}
    16.667%{background:#ff0;}
    33.333%{background:#0f0;}
    50%{background:#0ff;}
    66.667%{background:#00f;}
    83.333%{background:#f0f;}
    100%{background:#f00;}
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/500/?random">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").onmousemove = function() {
  //Set random background color
  myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
}
```

Demo:

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").onmousemove = function() {
  //Set random background color
  myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Hover ME !</div>
```

Comment: While `clearInterval` and `clearTimeout` *may* work interchangeably in most, if not all, browsers, you would provide better future-proofing by using `clearTimeout` here.

Comment: The mouse movement detection is exactly what i wanted, for the color i had in mind it scrolling through every color, like a rainbow effect rather then just switching between 2 colors. (While the mouse is moving the image will scroll through colors, when it stops the image stays at it's current color.)

Comment: @TheZelax The color set is random or you have some predefined set ?

Comment: Upvoted, but you still need to reset it to its original color when the mouse leaves

Comment: @Mi-Creativity thank you ! please take a look at the second comment the OP wants that when the mouse stops the image stays at the current color.

Comment: oh sorry didn't read that comment, thanks for clarifying, that made it much easier :)

Comment: I had in mind the colors to scroll through a color wheel, like going from light blue to dark blue, then into light purple, then dark purple, basically a color wheel like this one [link](https://color.adobe.com/build2.0.0-buildNo/resource/img/kuler/color_wheel_730.png)
I'm not very good at java script, but perhaps some way of scrolling through a hue value or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting here as I need almost something like this. I need to change the back ground position on each mouse move. Image is set as background, here is the image:

http://pbdlbd.org/ipositive/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/one10.jpg

And I want to move the background position on each mouse move. This image has 4 parts(height of each part is 523px) and first it will show the top portion and after mouse move over  it will show the 2nd portion and on another mouse move it will show 3rd portion and after 4th part it will repeat for further mouse move over it. After mouse is removed from the image, it will show the default top portion of the image.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("#ipos .flex_cell").onmousemove = function() {
  //Set background position 523px bottom on each mouse move
  #ipos .flex_cell.style.background-position = center -523px (here i can't make it so that it changes to -1046px by code);
}
```

[Here](http://pbdlbd.org/ipositive/) is the site

TIA